# MySQL Workbench doesn't save settings

Tags: mysql-workbench

For example, I need to export data with blob in the hex format. But everytime I reload Workbench, the default settings are restored and I need to remember to go check the 'hex-blob' setting. How can I prevent this behavior ?

Comment: I have this same problem with my Windows version, and since I'm using MariaDB and need to change the default mysqldump, it can be pretty annoying. Also who tf wants their default id column to be named "tableid"? I'd love it if there were an answer to this...